# Problem with the Wightman axiom about the transformation law of the fields

Tags: functional-analysis, mathematical-physics, quantum-field-theory

The axiom in the title is almost always stated as
$$
U(a, A)^{\dagger} \phi(x) U(a, A)=S(A) \phi\left(A^{-1}(x-a)\right)
$$
or, more precisely, as
$$
U(a, A) \phi_n(f) U(a, A)^{-1}=\sum_{m=1}^N S\left(A^{-1}\right)_n^m \phi_m((a, A) \cdot f)
$$
where the terms and the notation can be found on Wikipedia or on Folland's book.
I do not know how to interpret the summation on the right, because generally it is not possible to sum two unbounded operators unless they have the same domain.
Should I interpret the equality as
$$
\langle\eta|U(a, A) \phi_n(f) U(a, A)^{-1}|\theta\rangle=\sum_{m=1}^N S\left(A^{-1}\right)_n^m \langle\eta|\phi_m((a, A) \cdot f)|\theta\rangle
$$
for any $\eta, \theta$ in the dense subspace $D$ of the Hilbert space?

Comment: Can you plz attach the Wikipedia link So I get the notation.

Comment: Okay Yes the equality of 2nd equation is correct, that because of the axioms,  Firstly, When you input a function at x=f and A^-1 and A commute so f has a length in a Tuple so there are N coordinates where fix n.So basically Phi_m(a,A,f) Define a projection type of thing which should be overall all possible coordinate.Hence It is defiend I guess.

Comment: I am quiet in doubt of my answer though, you might ask this in physics stack exchange , but 2nd equation is surely correct in terms of compositions of operators and $\phi_m((a,A).f)$ which runs over $m=1,2,..,N$ in mathematical terms projections now remove n it's still true but .

Comment: In other words for all integers $n$ it is ture , But surely you should check by some else Because I might be wrong. In mathematical terms it's defining projections for sure. But due to ugly notation it's hard to understand.

Comment: And please after Checking Let me know The answer too.

Comment: The answer is yes, the vectors are assumed to be in a dense subspace given a priori (axiom W1 in the not so great Wikipedia page).